# Post webservice is not working in Android

Tags: android, web-services

I am new to Android as well as webservices. I have never used post webservice. Tried as below but it is neither showing success nor failure.

If I use the advanced rest client chrome extension, I am able to test and webservice is working perfectly just that it takes much time.

When trying to run from code, it immediately shows - after calling webservices - toast msg --> indicates it did not call the webservice.

Spent 2 days in it but no luck. Any suggestions?

```
 public void borrowBook(String barCode, String patronId)
    {
        final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 200000 * 1000000000;

        // Make RESTful webservice call using AsyncHttpClient object
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.setTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);

        progress.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        progress.setIndeterminate(false);
        progress.setCancelable(false);
        progress.show();

        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "B4 calling webservice", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        client.post("http://43.555.6.111:8081/SIPServices/SIc.svc/Checkout?barcode=B12&patron=thi", new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Response: " + response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("TAG", "Success");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String response, Throwable error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Status code :" + statusCode + "errmsg : " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet or remote server is not up and running]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("TAG", "Failure");
                    }

                }
        );
        progress.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "After calling webservice", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't set your parameters to anything, and you don't send them. 
Plus you're trying to do a post call, but the url are with get parameters: "http://43.555.6.111:8081/SIPServices/SIc.svc/Checkout?barcode=B12&patron=thi"

Also consider implementing the onStart method and log it, to see if it even starts.

Comment: I tried passing params separately too, but still not working.          client.post("http://43.555.6.222:8091/Sices/SIc.svc/Checkout"
                        ,params, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {

Answer (score 0):

This is my custom class to handle request. I use json here, you can return and type that you want. All you need are

- url: http://43.555.6.111:8081/SIPServices/SIc.svc/Checkout
- method: "POST"
- params: an arrayList of key and value: barcode=B12&patron=thi

  ```
  HashMap<String, String> mValueParams = new HashMap<>();
  mValueParams.put("barcode", "B12");
  mValueParams.put("patron", "thi");

  JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST",mValueParams);
  ```

  public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                        HashMap params) {

  ```
      sbParams = new StringBuilder();
      int i = 0;
      for (String key : params.keySet()) {
          try {
              if (i != 0) {
                  sbParams.append("&");
              }
              sbParams.append(key).append("=")
                      .append(URLEncoder.encode(params.get(key), charset));

          } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          i++;
      }

      if (method.equals("POST")) {
          // request method is POST
          try {
              urlObj = new URL(url);

              conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

              conn.setDoOutput(true);

              conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

              conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

              conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
              conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

              conn.connect();

              paramsString = sbParams.toString();

              wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
              wr.writeBytes(paramsString);
              wr.flush();
              wr.close();

          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      } else if (method.equals("GET")) {
          // request method is GET

          if (sbParams.length() != 0) {
              url += "?" + sbParams.toString();
          }

          try {
              urlObj = new URL(url);

              conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

              conn.setDoOutput(false);

              conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

              conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

              conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

              conn.connect();

          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

      }

      try {
          //Receive the response from the server
          int status = conn.getResponseCode();
          InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
          result = new StringBuilder();
          String line;
          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
              result.append(line);
          }

      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      conn.disconnect();

      // try parse the string to a JSON object
      try {
          jObj = new JSONObject(result.toString());
      } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
      }

      // return JSON Object
      return jObj;
  }
  ```